# Android - set layout background programmatically

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have noticed that the *setBackground* method for the *RelativeLayout* object is targeted for API 16 (Android 4.1) and higher, but my application has the target API 8 and I cannot use it.

Is there any alternative solution for this problem (besides  marking the class/method with *TargetApi*(16) or changing the target API in the manifest)?
Thank you!

**Edit**: Eclipse was buggy and it showed me the same error for *setBackgroundDrawable* but now it seems to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use one of:

- [`.setBackgroundColor(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) (if you're setting it to a color)
- [`.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) (if you're setting it to a `Drawable` type; this is deprecated, and was replaced by [`.setBackground(Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29))
- [`.setBackgroundResource(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) (for setting a resource from `R.java`)

If you use the second one, make sure to do a conditional check on your API version:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    view.setBackground(...);
else
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(...);
```

... and mark it with `@TargetApi(16)` and `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.

Comment: ah I know of the .setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) method but to me the IDE had the same error with api 16 requirement. I am using Eclipse and it seemed to be a bug after reopening the ide and cleaning the code a bit it worked. Than you very much and sorry for trouble.

Comment: @sethengine Don't worry about the trouble--we're here to help! Glad you've solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you want to set a color as the background, use [`setBackgroundColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29). For a Drawable, you can use the now deprecated method [`setBackgroundDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) for APIs below 16, and [`setBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) for API 16 devices. You can also use [`setBackgroundResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) for setting a resource as the background.

Note that while a lot of methods are marked as deprecated, I'm yet to come across one that has actually been removed. So while you could use the deprecated method even in API 16, I'd recommend setting your target API to 16 and using an if else to switch between the methods, depending on the API version the device is running.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setBackgroundDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) instead. It does the same thing, but it's been deprecated since the new `setBackground()` method.