# Where/how do you use Android Annotations?

Tags: java, android, annotations, setbackground

I need to change the background of a view programmatically so I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678949/android-set-layout-background-programmatically).  It says to make sure that you mark it with annotations.  Where do I do that?  I've tried the top of the class, the top of the method, inside the method.  I'm confused.  It's a little bothersome that I even need annotations to do this very simple/common thing anyway.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
    android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    rowView.setBackground(R.drawable.blue_background);
}
else {
    rowView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.blue_background);
}
```

The `setBackground` method gives me an error saying it is only available for APIs level 16 and above while my app supports lower than that.

The `setBackgroundDrawable` method is deprecated as of API level 16.

I'm being told to use `@TargetApi(16)` and `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` but where?  I'm using Eclipse for my IDE on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you double-click on the error, Eclipse will create an auto-fix and the problem should disappear.