# Change background image of a different activity

Tags: android

Say I have activity 1 and activity 2, and image A and image B.

Currently, on activity 2 I have the background image set to image A, is there a way to change that background image to image B from inside of activity 1?

Edit:

I tried

```
    LinearLayout layoutBg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity2);
    layoutBg.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

from inside for activity 1, but I get a nullpointerexception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.imperostudio.meddit.StepTwo.onResume(StepTwo.java:141)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1198)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5530)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Look at the log, there is a Null Pointer Exception at line 41 of StepTwo class (onResume method). You are trying to get LinearLayout in activity 2 inside activity 1

Comment: [Android - set layout background programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678949/android-set-layout-background-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save primitive data: Like `strings` And CHECKING/MATCHING .

### [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store the desired background and upon creating Activity2 you can read the background again from `SharedPreferences` and set it properly. Do it like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(KEY, VALUE);
editor.commit();
```

And read it like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
try {
    String value = sharedPrefs.getString(KEY, defaultValue);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess above answers wont work as user2809361 wants to change the image in realtime.The best option would be to use broadcast recievers. use this code in activity 2

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // change your image from here you can get the image link from intent
        }
    };
registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, new IntentFilter(...));
```

and then from activity 1 use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("image", "imagelink");
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

this will trigger your broadcast receiver in Activity 2 and it will call the method on receive then you can do your task there.

Hope this helps!!